# javascript copy object value from "schema" object

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

here is the situation. I got a an object contain lot of information, for example

```
var a = {
  one:"foo",
  two:"bar"
}
```

and now I want to provide and other object contained specify key. for example

```
var schema = {
  two:""
}
```

then just create a new object base on key of schema

here , I would like to use lodash / moutjs or any lib

sorry for poor eng

Comment: From what I understand: `schema.two = a.two`

Answer (score 2):

With lodash you can [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) the schema [`_.keys()`](https://lodash.com/docs#keys) from the originalObj (the one you named a):

```js
const originalObj = { one: "foo", two: "bar" }
const schema = { two: "" }

const result = _.pick(originalObj, _.keys(schema))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you want pure JS, you can [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the schema [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const originalObj = { one: "foo", two: "bar" }
const schema = { two: "" }

const result = Object.keys(schema)
  .reduce((obj, key) => 
    originalObj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? { ...obj, [key]: originalObj[key] } : obj
  , {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure that I understood you correctly. But, for example, you can use `pick` in [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#pick).

```
var a = {
    one:"foo",
    two:"bar"
}
var schema = _.pick(a, "two"); // returns {two: "foo")
```

Note, that also working in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#pick).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library for a that simple operation. Here's a working code:

```
var copyObject = function(origin, keys) {
  var destination = {};
  for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(origin.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
      destination[keys[i]] = origin[keys[i]];
    }
  };
  return destination;
};

var a = {
  one:"foo",
  two:"bar"
};

var schema = copyObject(a, ['two']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var copyObject = function(origin, keys) {
  var destination = {};
  for (var i = keys.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(origin.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
      destination[keys[i]] = origin[keys[i]];
    }
  };
  return destination;
};

var a = {
  one:"foo",
  two:"bar"
};

var schema = copyObject(a, ['two']);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.